# Global variable inside function scope not working - async.series

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a global variable for the function in order to use it in all functions inside a scope. Functions are called one after another using `async.series` :

```
  exports.update = function(req, res, next){

    var result = {};      // setting global var for the scope

    var function1 = function(callback) {
      MyModel.findOne(conditions)
        .lean()
        .exec(function(err, docs) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(err, null);
          }

          result.docs = docs; // assigning function result to global var

          return callback(null, 'done');
        });
    };

    var function2 = function(callback) {
      var fieldsToSet = {
        // ...
        somefield: result.docs.someproperty // error here result.docs = null
      };

        Mymodel.create(fieldsToSet, function(err, record) {
          // ...
        });
    };
    };

    require('async').series([function1, function2]);
  };
```

Returns error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'someproperty' of null
```

How in this case I get the property? Thank you.

Comment: do you have something inside your result.docs ?

Comment: Sounds like the `docs` you're getting back in the first function is `null`. Otherwise, you'd be getting an error saying you're trying to read a property on `undefined`.

Comment: The strange thing - the main function actually does its work, but falls with an error. After restarting a server I get what I need.

Comment: @ Mike C If I am deleting the record from `function1` , in one of my next functions inside a scope, can it turn to `null` ? Can it be the cause?

Comment: @ASem It can only be set to `null` if you set it to `null`. If you are only ever assigning it using `result.docs = docs` then this means the `docs` **must** be `null`. If not there, then somewhere else you are assigning `null` to `result.docs`.

Answer (score -1):

*Old answer*

Declare `result`outside of `exports.update`. Must work in this case.

EDIT : Probably make `result` equal to an empty object *inside* the function as well, if that's what you want.

---

*New answer as of December 17th*

@ASem : if you're still up for it, maybe define `result.docs = {};` *right* under `result` ?

Comment: `result` is available in both functions. Otherwise they'd be getting an error trying to access `result`, not `someproperty`. Edit: But then `result` wouldn't be available in other functions *and* could not be used to collect data from multiple functions.